# sorting array by custom order in Coldfusion

Tags: arrays, sorting, coldfusion

Ive got an array of product sizes which can be varied.

some cases it will be.

```
08
10
12
16
18
S
M
L
XL
XXL
```

I appear to be able to sort the array of numeric values easily, however when the sizing has strings with it also, i cant seem to sort them in alphabetical order as well

Example
it ends up being

```
L
M
S
XL
XXL
```

technicailly speaking, this is correct for alphabetical order, but the order for it for human beings should be

```
S
M
L
XL
XXL
```

Would anyone know of a way to do this using Coldfusion ? Im currently using CF 8 and have looked everywhere for sorting, but cant seem to find out how to do it

Comment: Not an elegant solution, but you can loop through an array of your  order and pull elements out into a new array.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using CF10+, you're in luck!

https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArraySort

Implement your own callback function to sort your collection yourself, e.g.:

```
<cfscript>
    function sortSize(array sizes) 
    {
        var sizeOrder = "XXS,XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL";    // your sort order

        arraySort(sizes, function(s1, s2) {
            return listFindNoCase(sizeOrder,s1) - listFindNoCase(sizeOrder,s2);
        });

        return sizes;
    }
</cfscript>
```

Run the code above on TryCF: http://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad/pastebin?id=pb1rn6CT

**Update**: But since you're using CF8, you can implement your own bubble sort and try:

```
<cfscript>
    function sortSize(input) 
    {
        var local = {};

        local.sizes = "XXS,XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL";    // your sort order
        local.sorted = false;
        local.inputSize = arrayLen(input);

        while (!local.sorted) 
        {
            local.sorted = true;
            for (local.i = 1; local.i < local.inputSize; local.i = local.i + 1) 
            {
                local.size1 = listFindNoCase(local.sizes, input[local.i]);
                local.size2 = listFindNoCase(local.sizes, input[local.i + 1]);

                if (local.size1 > local.size2)
                {
                    arraySwap(input, local.i, local.i + 1);
                    local.sorted = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return input;
    }
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#sortSize(listToArray('l,M,M,s,XL,Xs'))#">
```

Run the code above on TryCF: http://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad/pastebin?id=uL7r9Uyf

Comment: Henry, I would have implemented this with some more efficient algorithm than bubble sort, plus I would have made it more generic and pass a comparator function into it. And - for Pete's sake... *tags*? Really?

Comment: @adamcameron cfscript in cf8 days was pretty awful. You are more than welcome to come up with an implementation and post on your own blog.  Merge sort?

Comment: There's nothing to any sorting algorithm I'm aware of that would not have been better-doable in CFScript in *any* version of C (since CFScript was added). I'd probably try to remind myself how a merge sort works, yes. Haven't coded one since I was @ Polytech in 1992 though.

Comment: @AdamCameron any version of CF you mean?  I thought I couldn't use `>`  but I just checked that was supported.

Comment: Comes to think of it, bucket sort would be the simplest and the quickest.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I don't want to go back to figuring out bubble, merge, or any other sorting algorithm.  I might take the following steps:

1. Set up a database table of all possible sizes with a numeric column for some sort of sorting criteria.
2. Cache or create that query in a application level singleton
3. Create a UDF that would convert your array to a query using CF8's version of [QueryNew](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_19.html) and it's affiliated functions.
4. Do a query of queries joining your sorted sizes to your unsorted array and order by the sortfield
5. Make sure you do a `left join` and make sure you capture the sizes that don't fit your original table so that you can error, report, or randomize, any data that comes in mismatched.

Encapsulate the entire process into a UDF or method of an application scoped singleton for repeated calls.