# In Coldfusion how do you order a list alphabetically then numerically

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

Say I have the following list:

```
<cfset myList = "1a,2b,3c,aa,bb,cc" >
```

How do I sort this list so that it will be "aa,bb,cc,1a,2b,3c"? In other words, I want anything that starts with a number to be at the end of the list and in order of the number it starts with.

Comment: What version of CF are you using?  Not exactly the same question, but you may want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048779/sorting-array-by-custom-order-in-coldfusion/25049147#25049147

Comment: That list has to come from somewhere.  Look for an opportunity to sort it properly as you generate it, not after you generate it.

Comment: @DanBracuk It's coming from the database, any sort by functions that would do this in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Henry had a working answer for my CF9 server however when I plugged in my list with 2000 or so items in it, this method would have a significant delay, so I ended up coming up with my own way of doing this which turned out to be super fast:

```
<cfset digits = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9">
<cfset numList = "">

<cfloop index="item" list="#arguments.input#">
    <cfif ListFindNoCase(digits, Left(item, 1)) >
        <cfset numindex = ListFindNoCase(arguments.input, item) >
        <cfset numList = ListAppend(numList, item)>
        <cfset arguments.input = ListDeleteAt(arguments.input, numindex) >
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfset numList = ListSort(numList, "textnocase", "asc") >
<cfset arguments.input = ListSort(arguments.input, "textnocase", "asc") >
<cfset arguments.input = ListAppend(arguments.input, numList)>

<cfreturn arguments.input >
```

Comment: Why not just sort it in your db query [as suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26617032/104223)? You did not mention your dbms, so you may need to tweak the sql.

Answer (score 5):

This will work if you are on CF10+.

```
<cfscript>
    values = listToArray("1a,2b,3c,aa,bb,cc");
    arraySort(values, function(e1, e2) {
        var diff = val(e1) - val(e2);
        if(diff != 0)
            return diff;
        return e1 < e2 ? -1 : 1;
    });
    writedump(values);
</cfscript>
```

Run: http://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad/pastebin?id=kKY9y2Nn

**UPDATE**

But since you're using CF9:

```
<cfscript>
    function customSort(input) {
        var sorted = false;
        while (!sorted) {
            sorted = true;
            for (var i = 1; i < arrayLen(input); i++) {
                var e1 = input[i];
                var e2 = input[i + 1];
                var diff = val(e1) - val(e2);
                if (diff == 0 ? e1 > e2 : diff > 0) {
                    arraySwap(input, i, i + 1);
                    local.sorted = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return input;
    }
    values = listToArray("1a,2b,3c,3a,aa,bb,cc");
    writeDump(customSort(values));
</cfscript>
```

Run: http://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad/pastebin?id=XK3fQv9T

Comment: My input is coming from the database I wouldn't know what it is before hand.

Comment: Sorry it worked in trycf, but I realized that I have CF9 in place so this actually won't work on my server. :(

Comment: Updated with a bubble sort solution for CF9.

Comment: I ended up answering my own question. Your method worked in CF9 however when I used my list with over 2000 items in it, I saw very significant delays.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using MySql. I am not sure whether it will work on others, but I think it should. You can do this on database level if the source of the values is a single column. Try this:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM   your_table 
ORDER BY IF(name RLIKE '^[a-z]', 1, 2), name
```

See this [runnable example on SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7b96/2)

Comment: Care to demonstrate this theory?

Comment: @Dan, I just left the office. I am on mobile now. I will do it tomorrow or you can create test table and check it out.

Comment: @DanBracuk, I have changed the query a little bit as earlier query was not supporting all scenario's but this query support all scenario's. I have also added an example on sqlfiddle. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it in the database.  It shows the general idea.  The specifics depend on the database engine which you didn't specify.

```
select field1, field2, etc
, case when substr(field1, 1, 1) between '0' and '9' then 2 else 1 end sortby
etc

order by sortby, field1
```

Comment: How would your sql look like for MS SQL?